# How can I check-in files in VSO with azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to do automate runtime generated files through pipeline , needs to do forcefully check-in current DEV branch but that step should skip in UAT / PROD branches. is it possible?

What I have done?

I added one command line task in the pipeline and calling some exe file which perform to generate the class files and copying in Project directory.

What needs to be done?
that file which copied in destination location it should do automatic checkin dev branch

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First to say, storing file(s) into source control during a pipeline is **not a recommended** way. It may pollute our source code.

Build artifacts should be pushed to a build drop or uploaded to an artifacts feed, not put back into source control.

If you insist on this. You could **use a powershell script** to handle the check in process.

Not sure which kind of version control you are using. Kindly check below samples:

- For TFVC:
  [How can I check-in files in TFS with azure pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766855/how-can-i-check-in-files-in-tfs-with-azure-pipelines)
- For GIT:
  [Azure DevOps pipeline task to update a file and check-in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304119/azure-devops-pipeline-task-to-update-a-file-and-check-in-tfs)

`check-in current DEV branch but that step should skip in UAT / PROD branches.`

You could speicify target branch in your script as need.

Comment: I am using Azure Devops Source control , Can you provide me some script/references.

Comment: @Sudhir Sorry for not clearing. It should be **version Control**. Either TFVC or GIT in Azure DevOps. Azure Repos supports two types of version control: Git and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC). You will choose this  when you create project. Details please refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops

Comment: Sorry I am using GIT in Azure Devops

Comment: @Sudhir Thanks for the info. You could either use Rest API follow above link. Or directly use Git command line. Kindly refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680490/how-to-add-update-files-in-git-repository-from-azure-devops-pipeline-dynamics-36 Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting below error: - 

C:\agent\_work\1\s>git push -u origin develop 
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://test.visualstudio.com': 
terminal prompts disabled

Comment: Hi sudhir, give a try  forcing git to use ssh. We do provide a ssh rul in Azure DevOps Git repo. Kindly take a look at this blog for more details https://jacopretorius.net/2018/05/git-error-could-not-read-username.html